# calculate precision and recall for SVM model in R

Tags: r

I use census-data to build logistic regression model and SVM model, first, I convert <=50K to 0, >50K to 1 to make the data binomial. I try to calculate precision and recall for both models and compare which model perform better. But `table(test$salary,pred1 >0.5)` for SVM model only gives fault values and no true values ( FALSE
 0    26
 1     8) . Does anyone know what the the problem is?

I am new to R software, I hope that I can get help from here.Thanks a lot. Any help is welcome. I hope the question is clear enough.

```
#setwd("C:/Users/)
Censusdata <- read.csv(file="census-data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
library("dplyr", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")

# convert <=50K to 0, >50K to 1
data = Censusdata 
data$salary<-as.numeric(factor(data$salary))-1
library(lattice)
library(ggplot2)
library(caret)
data <- Censusdata
indexes <- sample(1:nrow(data),size=0.7*nrow(data))
test <- data[indexes,]
train <- data[-indexes,]

#logistic regression model fit
model <- glm(salary ~ education.num + hours.per.week,family = binomial,data = test)
pred <- predict(model,data=train)
summary(model)

# calculate precision and recall 
table(test$salary,pre >0.5)
#  I get 
      FALSE TRUE
  0   26    0
  1    6    2

# for SVM model 
model1 <- svm(salary ~ education.num + hours.per.week,family = binomial, data=test)
pred1 <- predict(model1,data=train)
table(test$salary,pred1 >0.5)
# I get the following 
   FALSE 
0    26
1     8
```

Comment: Part of your problem may be rooted in your inconsistent renaming of data. For instance, you convert your `$salary` to a `numeric` for `df` but not for `data`, which is used for your table. (BTW: I suggests *against* using `data` for a variable name ... or any base R function, for that matter.)

Comment: Thanks for your help @r2evans.

Comment: I convert data$salary to numeric, it seems work a bit, but I only get False value for SVM model but no true values.